# Highcharts 4.1.1 adding a severe drop shadow to data labels if you specify a font color

Tags: highcharts

I've noticed that the latest version of Highcharts (v.4.1.1) is adding severe drop-shadows to data labels if you change the font color.

For example - Here is the jsfiddle for the bar chart demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/

Here is the exact same code, but with one change - the addition of a color parameter for the data label:

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#999',
            enabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/wgLnuft5/

This makes the labels effectively unreadable.

Can you prevent this, while still specifying a data label color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the shadow completely, or specify a specific shadow color instead.

Removing the shadow (by overwriting the default `textShadow` style) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgLnuft5/2/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#E0E0E0',
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                textShadow: ''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting a specific `textShadow` color ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgLnuft5/3/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#E0E0E0',
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                textShadow: '0 0 6px #FF3399, 0 0 3px #FF3399'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The default value for the `textShadow` is ([API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style)):

```
"textShadow": "0 0 6px contrast, 0 0 3px contrast"
```

The reason your specific color value is problematic is that when the color is set to `contrast` it tries to get the contrasting color of the text color. In this particular case the contrasting color is really similar to the text color, which makes it unreadable.

According to the API this style has been in use since version 4.1.0 of Highcharts.